# PHP - safely allow users to save html

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I'm writting a website that allows users to paste in html for their blogs.

The html they paste in will then get saved to a file and this is what will be read and changed when the user makes changes. The file will almost be like a complete web page so it will have all your normal tags; `head`, `body`, `div`'s, etc. etc.

This means it should allow almost all `html` and `css` tags apart from anything that could cause a security breach. So it essentially needs to strip `php` tags, certain style tags, and html/javascript `script` tags.

I looked into the `strip_tags` function but I'd rather not use that because:

> a) it removes html comments which I'd rather keep and
>
> b) it would be a lot of working specifying all the tags that it needs to ignore, considering I want it to ignore vastly more tags than I want it to strip.

My guess is that this is something regex-esc using `preg_replace`?

I'd like to add; I'm newly aware of XSS attacks through CSS too so any ideas/thoughts on how I could block certain css style tags out would be wonderful :)

Any ideas on what I could do?

Comment: No, please don't do this by yourself. There are plenty of free, tested and well-working libraries taking care of all this kind of things. Use them.

Comment: @Teemu What would you recommend for tackling this kind of thing in php?

Comment: There are a lot of well defined, used, and tested libraries to do that. You can further tinker with how much "freedom" you allow users for their input. But it's still worth considering some stuff - *who* are the users? Are they trusted to not be likely to do something harmful? Say, those could be your direct clients who want to maintain personal/professional blogs. In that case you can give them more freedom and expect them not to muck it up. If it's random users then, you should be more conservative. But also take care that a "trusted" user can be usurped or tricked into posting harmful stuff

Comment: @vlaz to answer your questions; no one can paste in html without an account and no absolutely none of them can be trusted! that's why I'm trying to get something rigid in place. If you could name a few of these libaries that would be a good place for me to start :)

Comment: No recommendations, just [pick yours](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+html+purifier). @vlaz I wouldn't compromize security checks on "save-client's-html-on-server" case in any circumstances, no matter who the clients are.

Comment: Also worth considering - do you *really* want to give the users complete control over the HTML content? You could use a markup language of some sort (e.g., Markdown) that will then be interpreted into HTML. Provide the users with a WYSIWYG editor and they should be able to replicate most styling they want. It's unlikely anybody really needs complete control over the HTML of *each* blog entry. There could be a separate admin-only access to define stuff for the site. At the very least it will make the blog look and feel consistent if each entry isn't completely different.

Comment: @Teemu wonderful stuff man! I'll have a nice flick through these.

Comment: @vlaz you make some great points, they would apply if what I explained in the Q was 100% accurate. There's a lot I missed out to make the question easily understandblae but it is an absolute must that users must be allowed to enter html :) Thank you very much for your answers though. When I find a solution, I'll update this post with the answer

Comment: `There's a lot I missed out to make the question easily understandblae` that's what I suspected, hence why I suggested considering it. I don't know if your circumstances allow for this. Perhaps it doesn't. Or perhaps, it doesn't allow it *right now* - again, I don't know the situation but maybe you have a requirement from "higher up" but you might be able to push back by coming up with good reasons and alternatives. Or perhaps, that's not possible, and you're stuck with this. Sometimes that happens, and you just do the best you can.